# What's the word for an alarm that goes so much such that it's ignored as inconsequential?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

At an old work-site I heard alarms that went off too frequently described as "chattering alarms", which is the best term I can think of so far.

> Chattering alarms (alarms that repeat excessively in a short time interval) create a level of nuisance to the operator. - [src](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0959152411001582)

However it's not quite right because I'd like something that maybe captures how it becomes ignored.

I also don't particularly mean it in a "boy who cried wolf" scenario in that eventually the alarm will be important, moreso just that when someone's constantly being warned or advised, they just tune it out as insignificant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In sociology of science, [obliteration by incorporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obliteration_by_incorporation) (OBI) occurs when at some stage in the development of a science, certain ideas become so accepted and common-use that their contributors are no longer cited.

Comment: In media it's called excessive overexposure.

Comment: Habituation - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48484/what-is-the-word-for-unconsciously-blocking-out-background-noises**strong text**

Comment: My bloody burglar alarm.

Comment: You will get dozens of answers from different disciplines. Which is why Single Word Requests require specific context and a sample sentence which gives a specific instance of how you want to use the word. Here's one common term - [nuisance alarm](http://www.jeffersontownky.com/index.aspx?NID=603)

Comment: Crying wolf is exactly what the alarm is doing. It does it so often that it's ignored, even when it is important.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [**false alarm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_alarm).  Any time the majority of alarms are false, tends to cause alarm fatigue and the subsequent ignoring of them.

Answer (score 1):

For a short form, Peter K's **false alarm** is good; in a narrative context there is also the fable of **[The Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf) who Cried Wolf**.